# Why is NSSArray not populating when parsing JSONArray?

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm a noob to iphone development and I'm trying to parse the JSONArray from this [link](http://bitcoincharts.com/t/markets.json).  The problem is that when this code is executed it returns that my NSArray contains only 4 values instead of 80 values that jSONArray at the link contains.  Am I properly converting the NSDictionary into NSArray.  Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm following this tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).

```
 //parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];
NSArray* bitcoin = json; //2
NSLog(@"size of bitcoin is %lu", sizeof(bitcoin));

// 1) Get the bitcoin rate mtgoxUSD
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(bitcoin); i++){
    NSDictionary* forex = [bitcoin objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *mtgoxUSD = [forex objectForKey:@"symbol"];
    NSLog(@"value against mtgoxUSD %@", mtgoxUSD);

    if (mtgoxUSD==@"mtgoxUSD") {
        NSString *bitcoinrate = [forex objectForKey:@"avg"];
        if (bitcoinrate==@""||bitcoinrate==NULL) {
            currencyBTC=1;
            NSLog(@"currencyBTC: is 1");
        }else{
            currencyBTC=[bitcoinrate floatValue];
            NSLog(@"currencyBTC: %f", currencyBTC);
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof` will return the size of the pointer structure in bytes, that's why you always see 4 as the value.

You should use the `count` method instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [bitcoin count]; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks. this works great!  I'm still having trouble getting the particular object i want at the line " if (mtgoxUSD==@"mtgoxUSD") " any suggestions on how to rectify this.

Comment: Nevermind, i changed the line to if ([mtgoxUSD compare:@"mtgoxUSD"] == NSOrderedSame) and got it working

Answer (score 1):

> "Am I properly converting the NSDictionary into NSArray"

No, not quite! `JSONObjectWithData` can return an array *or* a dictionary, depending on the JSON you're parsing. In this case, your JSON has a top-level array, so you don't need to convert it at all.

So first of all, replace your first few lines with this:

```
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                 options:kNilOptions 
                                                   error:&error];
```

You then want to iterate through your array, but your current iteration code isn't quite right. You can use the `count` method that pgb suggested in another answer, or alternatively you can use the really nifty 'fast enumeration' feature of Objective-C, which looks like this:

```
for id item in json {
    // Will iterate through all objects in the json array, accessible via item 
}
```